# Why interface is used in observer pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I have read in the book that the application layer is supposed to be independent of the presentation layer. Design pattern are solution to problem like that. Observer pattern is applicable when an object should be able to notify other objects without making assumptions about who those objects are.But a method such as addObserver adds the observers to the list of observers. After that, observerable know which objects are to be notified. And how those list are used? In the book I read, it said that the observerable only access observer through the interface defined in the application layer so that the layer architecture of the system is preserved. Then the interface use that list? lf so, what is the difference?

Comment: In you first sentence are you sure the book was not about the osI 7 layer model of networks

Comment: No, it is not. I m just reading a book titled practical object oriented design with uml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I stripped the not important parts of `java.util.Observable` a class designed for extension that consumes the `Observer` interface. This is Java code, but of course any OOP language could implement such pattern.

```
package java.util;

public class Observable {
    private boolean changed = false;
    private Vector obs;

    public Observable() {
        obs = new Vector();
    }

    public synchronized void addObserver(Observer o) {
        if (o == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        if (!obs.contains(o)) {
            obs.addElement(o);
        }
    }

    public void notifyObservers() {
        notifyObservers(null);
    }

    public void notifyObservers(Object arg) {
        Object[] arrLocal;
        synchronized (this) {
            if (!changed)
                return;
            arrLocal = obs.toArray();
            clearChanged();
        }

        for (int i = arrLocal.length-1; i>=0; i--)
            ((Observer)arrLocal[i]).update(this, arg);
    }

    protected synchronized void setChanged() {
         changed = true;
    }

}
```

An `Observer` is added to the `Observable` through the `addObserver` method. `Observable` maintains a list (here a `Vector`) of `Observer`s. When the `Observable` changes, `setChanged()` is called, followed by `notifyObservers()`. Each `Observer` has his `update()` method called to do something with the event. This is for the implementation details.

Now if you look from a design perspective. The `Observable` only knows of a list of `Observer`s. They could be anything. They could be heterogeneous: user interfaces, job handlers... All they need is to implement `Observer` and a single method. In Java, this principle is implemented in many specific places like the windowing toolkit Swing, for event handling.

Comment: But all the observer class implements an interface. In the book I read, it said that the observerable only access observer through the interface defined in the application layer so that the layer architecture of the system is preserved. Why and how? If an interface is not used, it violates the layer architecture?

Comment: Observable only access observers through the interface `Observer`, and their unique method (in Java): `update()`. Observables don't know the specifics behind each observer. `Observable` are closed yet the app is open for extension through the use of observers. An interface is a mean to decouple components from one another. How? By simply defining how to communicate: a set of methods each implementation of the interface is guaranteed to expose to its client (here the `Observable`). Why? Because you want to keep your application open for future changes, else we would do hardware not software.

Comment: :-)  Because I am a very dummy, please ask me like a very dummy. There can be many observers with different functions. Observable does not know and need not know how to notify to different observer classes. But using interface, it can call update function because all observer classes have update function because they implement that interface? Can I understand like that?

Comment: Yes, that's quite right. If you allow me to rephrase a bit, I'd say Observable need to know how to notify: that's the purpose of the interface really. Otherwise, you've got it.

Comment: :-)  Thank you very much. You have saved my life. I am very dumb.